# How to make Card Flip animation to support.v4.fragment work?

Tags: android

Trying to make card flip animation work with support.v4.fragment, following this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

Answer (score 0):

For animation donot think as it is so hard

use animation with following code

```
  Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.rotate);
        imageView.startAnimation(animation);  //image view is the widget in your respective layout file
```

Make a directory named anims in res folder and make a animation file named **rotate**

place this code there

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
    android:duration="750"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="15"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%">
</rotate>
</set>
```

This is for rotate animation and you can create yourself.